# How do I call javascript(node.js) function from plain old c++ function?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, callback, v8

I'm now struggling to integrate C++ library(zserge/webview) with V8. This library is designed to invoke C function whenever I run certain Javascript code on Webview.

As an example:

When you run this code below (inside a webview instance made by zserge/webview)

```
window.external.invoke('hello world');
```

then the C function is executed.

```
void my_cb(struct webview *w, const char *arg){
   ...
}
```

As I stated, I'm now integrating this with V8, so I want this function 'my_cb' to invoke Javascript function that I stored into a variable.

I made a function name as 'SetCallback' like below and exposed to node,

```
void SetCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> & args){
Environment *env = Environment::GetCurrent(args);
Isolate *isolate = env->isolate();

auto cb = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);

//g_callback is defined like this-> v8::Persistent<v8::Function> g_callback;
g_callback = v8::Persistent<v8::Function>::New(cb);

}
```

I thought that if I insert some code to my_cb I can invoke a function that I stored to `g_callback`.

So I coded like below:

```
void my_cb(struct webview *w, const char *arg){
Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

v8::Local<v8::Function> cb = v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(isolate, g_callback);

v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[] = {};

cb->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), 0, argv);
}
```

But this code doesn't work. I assume that my_cb is unsafe to call v8 function because it's outside of v8 instance. However, I don't know how I can fix this.

Thank you in advance, please help me fix this.

Comment: Try being more specific than "this code doesn't work". If you don't know what's wrong, compile in Debug mode, run in a debugger, and investigate.

Comment: Using v8 directly sounds awful. To call C++ code from javascript I recommend using the new nodejs NAPI. I made a boilerplate code template for this: https://github.com/Superlokkus/spielwiese/tree/napi